# Function m-files with loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop, logic

I need to make a function called newsign that inputs a

function handle (f) and

a real,positive, and small number (d).

I can assume that f(0) is not 0, that f(x) is continuous on [0,∞), and that f(x) crosses the x-axis somewhere  x > 0

for example

```
9-x-x^2
```

My function needs to use a while loop to calculate

```
f(x) at x=0,x=d,x=2d,x=3d.....x=
```

and so on until the very first x-value for which f(x) and f(0) have opposite signs, and then returns the value of x

This is what I have so far

```
function r=newsign(f,d)
  for i = 1:1000
     while (f(i*d) and f(0) ARE DIFFERENT SIGNS)
%I don't know how to do this
f=f(i*d)
r=(i*d)
     end
  end
end
```

ideally I would want i to count from 1:infinity only counting integers, but I am not sure how to do this, or if i even need a for loop at all.

Thanks!
For example if you plug in

```
   newsign(@(x) 9-x-x^2,0.1)
```

the answer will be

```
  2.600000000000001
```

Comment: So did my answer help?

Answer (score 1):

OK, well for one thing, you are nesting a `for` loop and a `while` loop together.  If you do this, the index `i` will always stay at `i=1` and the `while` loop will never stop executing because you are using the same point of `x=i*d` and it never changes.

As such, get rid of the `for` loop - just use `while` because you don't know when exactly it will terminate.  Also, if I can recommend something, use [`sign`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sign.html) or the signum function to check for the sign of a number.  However, if you don't wish to use `sign`, a common trick is to multiply the two numbers together and check if it's less than 0.  Should both signs of the numbers be the same, their product will be greater than 0.  If either one has an opposite sign, the product should be less than 0. In fact, this is what is commonly used in the bisection method when performing a root estimation.

As such, you would loop and keep incrementing with multiples of `d` **until** the signs between `f(x)` and `f(0)` are **unequal**, then quit.

As such:

```
function r=newsign(f,d)
ii = 1; %// Beginning index
while sign(f(ii*d)) == sign(f(0)) %// Loop until unequal signs
%while f(ii*d)*f(0) > 0 %// Can also do this too
    ii = ii + 1; %// Go to next index
    r = ii*d; %// Remember value of x
end
```

As such, this code should keep looping until `f(x)` and `f(0)` are unequal in sign.

Double checking with your example, we get:

```
>> newsign(@(x) 9-x-x^2,0.1)

ans =

    2.6000
```

... just as you expected.